# Map API Key for Windows 7

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to generate and MD5 certificate for my Map API Key for Debugging, the problem is, when I type this :

```
$ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

into the Command prompt, it says '$'is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file. 
Is this because I'm using Windows 7?
Also, there are no explicit instructions on the Dev guide for generating API Key on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `JDK 1.7` installed, `keytool` always outputs by default SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. you can get the MD5 Certificate by adding -v option.

use the following code:-

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

it will output MD5 certificate as well.